# match curly braces {} with sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I want to remove `\includegraphics` from `.tex` files in order to get a list of the filenames as illustrated in the following example. I want to remove `x` and `y` and get `I`

```
something {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{/tmp/myfile.pdf} somethingelse
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

The following example does not work with GNU sed 4.5. How should I escape the braces properly, so that it matches properly?

```
echo "something {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{" | sed -e "s/^*.\\includegraphics\[*.\]\{//"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't escape the `{` or `}`.  Doing so would make `sed` think you are using a regular expression repetition operator (as in `\{1,4\}` to match the previous expression between one and four times).  This is a basic regular expression operator, and the extended regular expression equivalent is written without the backslashes.

In an extended regular expression (as used with `sed -E`), you *do* want to escape both `{` and `}`.  If you find it hard to remember when to escape and when to not escape these characters, you may always use `[{]` and `[}]` to match them literally in both basic and extended expressions.

You also use `*.` in two places where I think you mean `.*`.  Incidentally, a `*` at the start of a regular expression (or just after `^` at the start) would match a literal `*` character.

As for the actual `sed` command, I would probably use the following:

```
sed 's/.*\\includegraphics.*{\([^}]*\)}.*/\1/' file.tex
```

To delete all lines that does not contain any `\includegraphics` command, you could add a simple `d` command:

```
sed -e '/\\includegraphics/!d' \
    -e 's/.*\\includegraphics.*{\([^}]*\)}.*/\1/' file.tex
```

This would work on your example, but not if the `somethingelse` at the end of the line contains a `{` character.

Comment: I don't know whether there can be lines with `includegraphics` but without filename in `{}`, which would not get removed, but anyhow I would suggest to print only lines with successful replacement: `sed -n 's/.*\\includegraphics.*{\([^}]*\)}.*/\1/p' file.tex`